# http_build_query without value on parameters (null value)

Tags: php, url, null, query-string

The PHP function [http_build_query](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) is quite handy for building an URL with GET parameters. But sometimes I like to use value-less "boolean" parameters, like so:

`/mypage?subscription-id=42&cancel-renewal`

Which I then check with a simple `isset`. Can I achieve this result with `http_build_query`?

**EDIT:** Assigning empty values to the parameter does not seem to work :

- `cancel-renewal => ''` results in `cancel-renewal=`
- `cancel-renewal => null` results in the parameter being omitted
- `cancel-renewal => false` results in `cancel-renewal=0`

Comment: http_build_query save data in variables in the form of associative array and then pass that as a parameters. While in get request you need to write a parameters in url. You may assign the `empty value` to that key.

Comment: I guess by doing `$query['cancel-renewal'] = "";`. I'm not sure..

Comment: @AaronJonk That results in `cancel-renewal=`

Comment: Why is that a problem? You can still use `isset()`.

Comment: Just that I find the URL prettier and more concise without the unneeded equal sign and value.

Comment: Why does that matter, it's never seen anywhere. `cancel-renewal` is the same as `cancel-renewal=`

Comment: FYI, when you send `cancel-renewal`, `$_GET['cancel-renewal'] is set to an empty string, just like when you send `cancel-renewal=`

Comment: True. But the question isn't whether it matters (which it doesn't; it's purely an aesthetic preference). Just whether it can be done.

Comment: You'll have to write your own replacement function, I don't think there's any way to make the built-in function do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I achieve this result with http_build_query?

No. Internally `http_build_query` appends the `=` key-value separator no matter what is the value of the parameter.
You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.3.3/ext/standard/http.c#L171) (PHP 7.3.3)

Means you either need to accept the `cancel-renewal=` look of the parameter or may be redesign the path to have something like `/mypage/cancel-renewal?subscription-id=42`

Third option would be to write your own simple function to build the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
$query = array("subscription-id" => 42, "cancel-renewal" => "");
$http_query = http_build_query($query);
```

This will return `?subscription-id=42&cancel-renewal=`. And works perfectly fine with `isset()`